# C - not evaluating condition

Tags: c, if-statement, intervals

do somebody know what could be problem in evaluating these conditions. integer should be assigned just in case it s in interval od -10000 to 10000 but it s not working. thank you

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int vstup1;
    int vstup2;
    int sucet = 0;
    int rozdil = 0;
    int soucin = 0;
    int podil = 0;
    float prumer = 0;

    printf("INPUT FIRST INTEGER\n");

    if (scanf("%d", &vstup1)&& vstup1 <= -10000 && vstup1 >= 10000) {
        printf("WRONG INPUT\n");
        return 0;
    }

    printf("INPUT SECOND INTEGER\n");
    scanf("%d", &vstup2); 
    if (vstup2 <= -10000 && vstup2 >= 10000) {
        printf("WRONG INPUT\n");
        return 0;
    }

    sucet = (vstup1 + vstup2);
    rozdil = (vstup1 - vstup2);
    soucin = (vstup1 * vstup2);
    podil =  (vstup1 / vstup2);
    prumer = ((vstup1 + vstup2)/2);

    printf("Desitkova soustava: %i  %i\n", vstup1, vstup2);
    printf("Sestnactkova soustava: %x %x\n", vstup1, vstup2);  
    printf("Soucet: %i + %i = %i\n",vstup1, vstup2, sucet);
    printf("Rozdil: %i - %i = %i\n",vstup1, vstup2, rozdil);
    printf("Soucin: %i * %i = %i\n",vstup1, vstup2, soucin);
    if (vstup2 == 0){
        printf ("Nedefinovany vysledek!\n");
        return 0;
    }
    else {
        printf("Podil: %i / %i = %i\n",vstup1, vstup2, podil);
    }
    printf("Prumer: %0.1f \n",prumer);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is it doing now? What do you want it to do.

Comment: Please note that a value can't be <= -10000 AND >= 10000. You need an `||` there.

Comment: yeah , thank you now it s working properly guys. :)

Comment: Please also note that probably the compiler warns you of unreachable code on conditions like that if the warning level is high as it should always be!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> `if (vstup2 <= -10000 && vstup2 >= 10000)    {`

There's no value for `vstup2` where it could be both less than or equal to -10000 AND greater than or equal to 10000. If this is the condition that's being skipped, it may be that the compiler is smart enough to see that the condition can never be satisfied. Perhaps you meant to use OR, like this?

```
vstup2 <= -10000 || vstup2 >= 10000
```